# Sort order arrow is displayed for all NSTableView headers?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nssortdescriptor

I've changed the sort descriptor for my NSTableView columns. The new descriptor is rockinggood, but now all headers have the sort arrow displayed.

[image]

[image]

Why? How can I leave the sort arrow for the header belonging to the column I'm currently sorting by ? This is the code (old descriptor is commented out):

```
        //Old descriptor
        //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:metadata.columnSortKeyPath ascending:NO selector:metadata.columnSortSelector];

        //New descriptor
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES comparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2)  {

            if ([obj1 isKindOfClass:[CBFolder class]])  {
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }

            if (currentClickedHeaderTableColumn) {
                CBTableColumnMetadata metadata = [(CBApplicationDelegate*)[NSApp delegate] tableColumnMetadataForKey:currentClickedHeaderTableColumn.identifier];
                return [[obj1 valueForKey:metadata.columnSortKeyPath] performSelector:metadata.columnSortSelector withObject:[obj2 valueForKey:metadata.columnSortKeyPath]];
            }

            return NSOrderedSame;
        }];
```

Comment: Ken is right, use _different_ `key`s for each column. If you do not have many columns a quick but dirty gotcha is that `self.self` is equivalent to `self`.

Comment: @renfei I tried self.self and it doesn't solve the issue. Still all columns have the arrow. Also, I don't understand the logic, If I pass @"self" as parameter I create a new string for each NSSortDescriptor, it's not the same object, right?  So how does it work: does it compare the string content (isEqualToString:) of each NSSortDescritpor?

Comment: Well, as for your first question, actually they _are_ the same object. This is because `@"self"` is a constant string, and in this case the compiler will optimize it so all occurrences of the same constant string share one underlying instance (they have the same address and you can print them with `%p` to verify). As for the `key`, I think yes, the _actual content_ matters in this case.

Comment: Ok about the first question. About the second one: if actual content matters, isn't @"self.self" exactly the same content?

Comment: Sorry about the unclear wording but by _actual content_ I mean the _literal content_, the string itself, not what it points to or can be evaluated to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe how it works is that the table view has its `sortDescriptors` property, which is the array of sort descriptors in effect (primary, secondary, etc.).

A column shows the sort indicator if its `sortDescriptorPrototype` matches the first element of the table view's `sortDescriptors`.

You appear to be using the same sort descriptor for all of your columns. Therefore, they all match and all show the sort indicator.

I think your sort descriptor is inherently broken because of its reliance on the `currentClickedHeaderTableColumn`. That suggests that each column's sort order changes as the "clicked" column changes, which is just broken. A given column's sort order (the order it *would* be in *if* the table were sorted by that column) shouldn't change depending on irrelevant state like that.

Comment: uhm, ok. I'm a bit confused, because I'm creating a NSSortDescritptor for each column: that code in the question is included in a for loop, therefore a different sort descriptor object is set for each column. If they are different objects, why all columns are affected?

Comment: In any case, how do you suggest to fix it?

Comment: I'm not certain how the sort descriptors are compared. It may be just by the `key`. Try using a separate key for each. If you must, you can make custom read-only properties which just return `self` but the key in the sort descriptor will still be different.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've tried to change the key but sorting doesn't work anymore. It seems that the correct key to use is @"self".

Comment: How did it no longer work? Was your new key effectively an alias for `self` or was it some actual property of the object? The key determines what values are passed to your comparator block, so you may need to take that into account.

Comment: Yes indeed, I need to pass the objects itself that why I specify "self". How can I customise a different key for each NSSortDescriptor if I need it to be "self"? I don't understand. My guess is that they are not compared based on the keys.

Comment: You can create a new read-only property that's just an alias for `self`. That is, declare a getter method like `- (id) sortKey1 { return self; }`. Then, you can use the key "sortKey1" for a sort descriptor. You can do something similar for the other columns.

Comment: I see, what if I have 45 columns (my case) and new ones can be added by the user?

Comment: Well, sort descriptors use the `key` via Key-Value Coding. So, you can generate some key string for each column that definitely doesn't correspond to any property on your object. Use some recognizable pattern or prefix. (Don't use periods.) Then, implement `-valueForUndefinedKey:`. Have it check for the pattern or prefix to see if it's one of those keys. If so, return `self`. If not, call super and return what it returns.